notation for double limits
I need to consider a double infinite limit for a function $f(v,w)$ where both $v, w$ go to infinity.  Is

the correct notation?  The main point I want to emphasize is that there is no ordering, e.g. I do not want
$\lim_{v\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{w\rightarrow\infty} f(v,w)$
Thanks!
p.s. How would I type the double limit above in math stackexchange?  I tried
$
\lim_{ \substack{v\rightarrow \infty \\ w \rightarrow \infty}}} f(v,w)
$

but it does not come through.

I think you can also use $$\lim_{(v,w)\to(\infty,\infty)}.$$

This is not well-defined. The limit a priori depends on how quickly $v, w$ are going to $\infty$ with respect to each other, e.g. it matters if $v = w$ or $v = w^2$ or $v^2 = w$ or whatever other curve you can imagine. An easy example here is $f(v, w) = \frac{v}{w}$.

@QiaochuYuan What if in some example it does not matter as in $$f(v,w)=\frac1{vw}?$$ If it does not matter, then the limit is defined. This is not always (maybe rarely) the case though.

In that example it also doesn't matter whether you take the limit one at a time in either order. I don't know if there's an example where this is different from the "double limit." This just doesn't seem like a well-behaved notion to me.

Thanks for all the comments, and especially for the counterexample by @QiaochuYuan.  In my specific case, how quickly each of $v, w$ goes to infinity does not matter.  I wonder what is the best way to state this (short of writing a paragraph)?

But it is just the same as $$\lim_{(1/v,1/w)\to(0,0)}.$$

You can also use $\lim\limits_{v,w\to\infty}f(v,w)$. There is nothing special about $\infty$ here. For the limit to exist, it must be independent of the path of approach. Saying "$v,w\to\infty$" just means that $v$ and $w$ must eventually escape any ball around $0$. This precludes taking the limits one at a time.

Posting this as an answer because it is too long for a comment (but it is intended to respond to some of the comments).
The clear example demonstrating one can take limits like this without caring about the path is of course the derivative of a holomorphic function $ f(z)$ with respect to $z=x+iy.$ Personally, If I were reading notation like $\lim_{(v,w)\to (a,b)}f(v,w)=c$ I would typically interpret that as saying:
For all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a ball $B=B_\delta ((a,b))$ such that \begin{equation*}(x,y)\in B\implies f(x,y)\in B_\varepsilon(c).\end{equation*} I'd guess that a ball should be taken in the sense of the box/product topology or in the metric on the product space (they are equivalent for finite products). If this limit $c$ exists it clearly does not depend on the choice of path with which one enters the ball $B$.
In the case of infinity one simply needs to take balls about infinity in the topology in question. This depends on the problem in question: for example, considering the complex upper half plane together with the point $i\infty$ one simply lets the balls about $i\infty$ be \begin{equation*}B_\delta(i\infty) = \{z\in\mathbb C:\Im z>\delta\}.\end{equation*} For the typical case of a limit towards infinity on the real line one does a similar thing, taking the balls about infinity to be the complements of the half open intervals $(-\infty,\delta]$.
For the two variable problem you might let a ball about infinity (here I mean $(\infty,\infty)$ as in the original question) be the product of a ball about $\infty$ in each coordinate. This is nearly equivalent to mpw's comment, except it specifies that one is approaching, say, positive infinity. All this is to say that yes, such a limit can be well defined, and I would denote it in the same way as user7777777, namely
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{(v,w)\to (\infty,\infty)}f(v,w).
\end{equation*}
This has the advantage of making it quite clear what both variables are tending to.
